# javaScript - dispatchEvent(event) not working

Tags: javascript, automation

I'm trying to trigger an enter key press on a (search) text box using dispatchEvent but the text box does not respond to the event.

Assuming that the variable "eventName" = "keydown"

```
function os_RaiseEvent(eventName) {
    var element = document.querySelector('[id$="_text"]');
    var event;
    if (document.createEvent) {
        event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        event.initEvent(eventName, true, false);
        if (eventName == "keydown" || eventName == "keyup") {
            event.keyCode = 13;
        }
        element.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
    else if (document.createEventObject) {
        event = document.createEventObject();
        if (eventName == "keydown" || eventName == "keyup") {
            event.keyCode = 13;
        }
        element.fireEvent("on" + eventName, event);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think your solution has critical problems, excuse me but let's review, why you wanna simulate Enter key down? just like you sain, you can do everything you want after firing your custom event by `document.addEventListener('customEvent', () => { console.log('do something')})`

Comment: I am creating an automation that updates a series of items in an online database. The database uses a search box in which the automation enters the UIN but there is no search button available for us to use. The only way to proceed after typing the UIN is to press the enter key in the search box